# Auto-refetch a mutation by invalidating its tag from another mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Can I auto-refetch `getEmployees` mutation by invalidating its tag from another mutation called `deleteEmployee` in the code below?

```js
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import customFetchBase from './customFetchBase.js'

export const publicApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'publicApi',
  baseQuery: customFetchBase,
  tagTypes: ['employees'],
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getEmployees: builder.mutation({
      query: ({
        formData = "defaultHashedDataString",
        salt = "xyz",
        pageIndex = 1
      }) => ({
        url: '/Hafez/Employee/Data',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          RequestVerificationToken: salt,
          FormData: formData,
          currentPage: pageIndex + 1
        }
      }),
      providesTags: ['employees']
    }),
    deleteEmployee: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ formData, salt }) => ({
        url: '/Hafez/Employee/Delete',
        method: 'POST',
        body: { RequestVerificationToken: salt, FormData: formData }
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['employees']
    })
  })
})

export const { useGetEmployeesMutation, useDeleteEmployeeMutation } = publicApi
```

Now when I call `deleteEmployee` mutation the `getEmployees` mutation does not run.

I know that I should use a GET request for getting data from server but for some security it can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries ***provide*** tags, mutations ***invalidate*** them. It seems to me that `getEmployees` should be a query instead of a mutation. When the `deleteEmployee` endpoint is called and successfully invalidates the `"employees"` tag, then any current subscribers to the *now* `useGetEmployeesQuery` hook will automatically trigger the `getEmployees` query to refetch.

```js
export const publicApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'publicApi',
  baseQuery: customFetchBase,
  tagTypes: ['employees'],
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getEmployees: builder.query({ // <-- update to query
      query: ({
        formData = "defaultHashedDataString",
        salt = "xyz",
        pageIndex = 1
      }) => ({
        url: '/Hafez/Employee/Data',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          RequestVerificationToken: salt,
          FormData: formData,
          currentPage: pageIndex + 1
        }
      }),
      providesTags: ['employees']
    }),
    deleteEmployee: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ formData, salt }) => ({
        url: '/Hafez/Employee/Delete',
        method: 'POST',
        body: { RequestVerificationToken: salt, FormData: formData }
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['employees']
    })
  })
});

export const {
  useGetEmployeesQuery, // <-- updated hook name
  useDeleteEmployeeMutation
} = publicApi;
```

Please note that the endpoints are either queries or mutations and that this is completely independent from the request method, e.g. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc.

Comment: I didn't now that we can set {method: "POST"} for a rtk query builder.query method, i will test it...thank you very much Drew

Comment: @AlirezaMohammadi Yup, you sure can. Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!